# 3D to 2D Objects in Android's Open GL not rendering because of culling

Tags: android, opengl-es, render, glu

In an attempt to use the same object in both the 3D world and 2D world of Android's OpenGL, I am unable to render the same object in both GLU perspectives.

For example, when I perform the following command:

```
GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 45.0f,(float)GlobalConfiguration.getWidth()/(float)GlobalConfiguration.getHeight(),0.1f,1000.0f);
```

I must make sure that my object is rendered like this...

```
gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CCW);
gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
gl.glCullFace(GL10.GL_BACK);
```

But then when I change the perspective to:

```
GLU.gluOrtho2D(gl,0,GlobalConfiguration.getWidth(),GlobalConfiguration.getHeight(),0);
```

The object will not render unless I either disable culling or redefine the order of the vertices in the index buffer.

Now the reason I need to stick to the way the 3D world works is that is because that is how my modeling software saves it's objects. (Blender)

Does anyone have any idea why that is? I want to still use culling (enable it) but I want an object to be renderable in both 3D and 2D.

Answer (score 0):

So the answer to this question was rather interesting... you CANNOT translate the gl matrix using the glTranslatef method more than 1f in the z direction! My objects z position were around -50f and when the call to glTranslatef() happened, I translated my object not between 0f and 1f and the object was not visible!

What a waste of a day...